# Why MySQL data messed up after instal whmcs panel?

Tags: php, mysql, whmcs

I have upgraded my panel to WHMCS 6.2.0 and my data messed up like 'Ù†ØµØ±ØªÛŒ',
So I executed the following command :

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

but now I have same problem, how can I correct it?
I am new in PHP, MySQL.